# How to publish a silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I want to publish my silverlight application with my WCFweb service.

Can somebody please give me a step by step process

Comment: If you are having a specific error you should mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete tutorial : http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/web-services-and-silverlight/